# Pandas transpose multiple rows into a single column

Tags: pandas

I'm sure this is simple, but it's thwarting me.  I have the many rows with many values and I want to transpose every row into a single column.

```
0 1 2 3 
a b c
4 5 6 7 8 9 
d e f g
```

And I want:

```
0
1
2
3
a
b
c
4
5
etc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.stack()` try it

Comment: Thanks Wen.  That did it.